# Не могу восстановить базу данных на SQL Server 2014 Enterprise

Tags: sql-server, filestream

Всем привет! Я пытаюсь установить базу данных, созданную в SQL Server 2008 R2 developer edition в SQL Server 2014 Enterprise. Я сделал бэкап базы данных на SQL server 2008, включил `filestream` на SQL Server 2014 (в Configuration Manager и в окне запросов SQL, перезапустил сервер), но все равно, когда я пытаюсь восстановить базу данных на SQL 2014, он пишет сообщение об ошибке - "не включен `filestream`". Самое безумное, что я уже делал эту операцию на другой машине с той же базой данных и версиями серверов, и там все работало.
 Что может быть не так?

Comment: Да включено же и с базами с другого экземпляра SQL 2014 все работает. Только с восьмерки не получается.

Comment: То есть у вас на этом же инстансе другие базы с `filestream` работают?